# This class does not define an IdClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My for class `Class1Item` is a reference to an entry in `Class1`. Hibernate needs me to define an `@IdClass`. Defining an own Class with the `Id` of `Class1` did not work for me.

Here is the error I am getting:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'bookItemRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   This class [class de.models.Class1Item] does not define an IdClass

Relevant Classes which are all in the same package:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(Class1ItemId.class)
public class Class1Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="reference")
    private Class1 class1;

    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long number;

    @Column(name="date_one")
    private LocalDate date1;

    @Column(name="date_x")
    private LocalDate dateX;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userReference")
    private User userReference;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="waitingUsers")
    private List<User> waitingUsers;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="enumX")
    private EnumX enumX;

}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Class1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String key;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String nameF;

    @NotBlank
    private String nameL;

    private String path;
}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="UserID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="email",unique=true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="user_firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="user_lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="isAdmin")
    private Boolean isAdmin;

    @ManyToMany
    @Column(name="wantedItems")
    private Set<Class1Item> wantedItems;

    @OneToMany
    @Column(name="borrowedItems")
    private Set<Class1Item> itemsBorrowed;
}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Class1ItemId implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String key;
}
```

How do I fix this error when there's actually an IdClass defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an @IdClass defined, but not the key re-declared in your ClassItem @Entity. They must match.

You need to add them like so:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Class1ItemId.class)
// others
public class Class1Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String key; // from your Class1ItemId

  // others

}
```

Comment: What do I do about 

 `private Class1 class1;`in Class1ItemId.java?

Comment: It looks like a \@ManyToOne to me, not an \@Id field, so you remove the \@ID. In general, it makes more sense to give your code proper names here, as it is quite difficult to map between class1, class1item, class1itemid in your head :)

Comment: In this example you'd have to think of Class1 as a car model with the specs defined while Class1Item is the actual car, an instance of which in a database. Say an "instance" of Car would be "VW Golf" while a class1Item would be the actual car, with the owner and so on defined. 

I used placeholder names for further abstraction.